# AQ Prince Aaron ability clarification

Tags: arcadia-quest

Prince Aaron's ability reads

```
All Enemies Close to him have -2 defense against attacks made by him or his Allies.
```

Does `-2 defense` mean `-2 defense dice` that the target gets to roll or does it mean that the target gets to roll his/her defense dice but has to subtract 2 from the result? If the latter, then does the subtracted defense still count as "saves"? For example, if the target rolls 3 shield after being attacked by Prince Aaron from a Close space, does that count as 3 saves or 1 save even though in the end the target only cancels out 1 hit?

Crossposted on [BGG](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1286345/prince-aarons-ability-clarification)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Throughout the rules, "Defense" refers to the number of dice rolled in defense of attacks.

> If the targeted Character has any Defense listed on his card, the player controlling him gathers a number of white Defense dice equal to that character’s Defense.